# How to disable ASP.net custom errors only for a specific IP address?

Tags: asp.net

Does anyone have any idea how to disable asp.net custom errors only for a specific ip address? this will ease debugging exceptions on my server from my office..

Comment: Can't do this AFAIK. CustomErrors is application-specific, not request-specific.

Answer (score 2):

Despite this is a quite old question, i've just got this problem on my environment to solve, and searched how.

There's no obvious way, but i've found [this alternative](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/troubleshoot-asp-net-errors-remotely-while-appearing-local):

You must setup 
App webconfig > system.web > customErrors > mode TO RemoteOnly

Witch means that you'll just see error on localmachine.

There are 3 steps to leverage RemoteOnly from a remote location.

1. Set RemoteOnly for customErrors
2. Have server administrator approve server variable REMOTE_ADDR
3. Create URL Rewrite rule

See the entire post for details.

Finally, you need to create a rule that can tell that it’s you visiting, and changes REMOTE_ADDR to 127.0.0.1 to make you appear local.

There are multiple ways to tell if it’s you.  One is by IP address.  This is probably the easiest in most cases, but be careful if you have a dynamic IP, that it could change over time and expose your detailed errors to someone else.

All this is a **Scott Forsyth** post, that i've found, and copied some parts.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly I am not aware of anything inbuilt. But If I were to solve this, I would add a HttpModule and hookup event handler for Application_Error event and in that handler I would try to find who is the client and what to do with it further.

Comment: So you would then compare the IP address to the subnet mask in order to determine if the request originated from outside the network?

Comment: @eddy556 - No, I was not thinking of that complicated. Something simple like Request.UserHostAddress will get me the host, and then we also have to remembers, that he is pretty clear about for which server he want to prevent the address, so we can check if the address is same as local, then dont raise the error. Please correct me if this is not appropriate.. I would also learn..

Answer (score -1):

Instead of messing around with IPs you can make the custom errors only be displayed when being debugged locally.  [Check here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx), look at the **mode** attribute.

Comment: Problem is I am not debugging locally

Comment: So you are debugging code on the server?  And reloading the live site as you make them to check your changes?

Comment: @m.edmondson I take it you're shocked/surprised at this? If the OP is seeing unexplained, different behaviour on his live server to that on his local server, is it not valid to turn off custom errors for specific IP addresses? Seriously - I'm not having a go. I'd be keen to know what alternative approaches there are. Thanks.